# A program to reduce package count and clutter on Debian 9?

Tags: linux, debian, package-manager

I'm running Debian 9 and I've installed several packages, which probably left behind other packages and configuration files (and general clutter).

I've already run `apt autoremove --purge` and `apt clean`, and used Synaptic to find any orphaned packages.

I do notice that Debian uses about 50 - 100MB in terms of RAM than before. I'm sure there are a TON of dependency and random library packages left over from when I installed some dev stuff to compile projects.

Any suggestions? The closest thing I can think of is CCleaner or whatever it's called, but it's not on Linux and the alternative doesn't seem to remove left over packages.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at *another* [package called `deborphan`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/deborphan).
(Yes, installing another package to reduce your package count!)

[`deborphan`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/deborphan) looks for orphaned packages, that is, packages that have no link to your dependency tree (and so are safe to remove).